# Changing values in grouped dataframe based on first row value of the column in that group

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am using the below code to arrange some data. It is grouped by `'ID'` and `'L'` and I have used a condition to print True in the `MT` column if it is `True`. What I want is that When the first row of the group is true, every other row in that group should print true irrespective of the condition (e.g in the output below,the fifth row in MT column should also show True, because the first row evaluated to true).

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'TS' : [20,25,30,35,45,50,55,58,65,75,60,62,72,77],"ID" : [22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24],"L" : [1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2]})
df2=(df.assign(TS=df['TS'].abs())
    .groupby(['ID','L'])['TS'].agg([('Min' , 'min'), ('Max', 'max')])
    .add_prefix('TS'))
df3=(df2.assign(WT=df2['TSMax']-df2['TSMin'])
    .assign(MT=df2['TSMax'].gt(df2.groupby('ID')['TSMin'].shift(-1))))
df3
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: "When the first row of the group is true". Is a "group" one ID? So ID 22 is one group, ID 23 is one group, etc?

Comment: @Sandertjuhh, Yes 22, 23, etc. are separate groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby`, index on the MT column, and then `transform` with a lambda that checks if the value is True.

```
df3['MT'] = df3.groupby('ID')['MT'].transform(lambda x: x.values[0] if x.values[0] else x)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This will also transform all rows that start with False to be full of False, I believe OP only wants to forward fill if the first row is True

Comment: @NuriTaş you're right, I missed that condition. Changed it to a lambda that checks for the condition. Thanks!